# how to recover deleted files from private mode in samsung a5

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow

i tried lot of android data recovery tools like wondershare dr.fone,minitool recovery etc. but wondershere cannot root my samsung it failed at 90% and other data recovery application cannot dug deep to recover deleted file from private mode of my smartphone.

Comment: What's your specific question? How to root or how to recover?

Comment: i have deleted files from private mode of samsung A5. i want to recover those files but without rooting my mobile or temporary rooting(rooting during the process only) my mobile